# iOS Push Notifications not working with AdHoc Certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

iOS Push Notifications not receiving with AdHoc Certificate. A different device token is also getting generated and in backend there is no error. But the device is not receiving Notification.

Comment: put some code here....how can we know where is the problem???

Comment: Is your app in background? App should be in background or closed in order to receive push notification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow this link step by step....

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

While creating Production SSL certificate, do not change the name "aps_production.cer".

And before creating Development related certificates, first create certificates(SSL,provisioning,p12) for only production.

It really worked for me after trying different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, Xcode picks one of the Provisioning Profiles in my machine even if I set it to the correct one.

What I did is, everytime I export,

*(WINDOW > ORGANIZER)*
[image: WINDOW > ORGANIZER]

I check the Provisioning Profile in the summary. If it is not the provisioning profile that exists in the developer account, I click the arrow (in the right of the provisioning profile) to see finder then I delete it from my machine.

[image]

After that, I tried to export again until I see the correct provisioning profile.